# Explain this CSS link underline animation

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-element

I'm trying to create a little animation so when I hover over a link it underlines the link from the middle - [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kLdcb8o7/)

The CSS code below works but I don't understand how it works. Please can someone break it down for me.

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
a:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: The `:after` creates an actual element inside the `a`.  [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/kLdcb8o7/2/) works the same, except without the fancy pseudo-element trick (so it should be easier to understand).

Answer (score 6):

`a:after` creates a block with empty inline text after link. Then `display:block`  makes it block type like for instance div default behaiour, so it goes to the next line with `height: 3px` and with `width: 0` (so not visible). And also centered because of `margin:auto`; Once you hover link this block gets the witdh and becomes visible. The `transition` attribute makes the animation work.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have `margin: auto`, the `:after` content is aligned to center of the `<a>` element, so the animation starts from center to 100% width of the `<a>`.

Comment: Thanks I was hoping for a more basic explanation, I'm not sure how the line comes because there is no border

Comment: That's how a :before or :after pseudo-element works. It takes properties of its own, as specified. This is something to read https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are asking about the code:

```
a:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

If you are not familiar with :before and :after, I will explain it. :before and :after mean to create an element that isn't visible to the document (you can't manipulate it with JavaScript), and is "designed" to be used to append small amounts of content before or after an element. However, that doesn't mean it has to be content. In your jsfiddle, it serves as a "expanding line" underneath the link. :before and :after behave almost like a child to the tag it is binded to (in this case your link).
Here is a reference link for what was discussed above [(reference link)](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/)

Ok, now we'll move on to the CSS properties...
The `content` property tells it what text to insert inside the :after/:before. The `content` property is required but you can leave it empty if you don't have any text that you want to append.

Ok, now for the `display:block;`...
:before and :after float by default. If you declare it as :before, the element floats to the left of the element selected, if it is :after, then it floats to the right. To make your :after go underneath the link, you must tell it to `display:block;`. You likely know this but `display:block;` means to not allow any other elements to "wrap" around the element. That is why when you create a `div` element it doesn't allow any other elements to go on the left or right of it.

Now for the `margin:auto;`...
This means to put the :after "element" in the (horizontal) center of the link. That is why when you hover over the link, it starts by expanding in the center. Try removing `margin:auto;` to see what it does and you will understand more clearly what I'm talking about here.

Now, the most interesting part! This is what makes it visible and "animate" when you hover over it. First we'll start with why you can't see it in the first place. You can't see it because it is 0px in width and the background color is transparent. If you look at the last line `transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;` this line is what makes the animation happen. It means that when the `width` property is modified, to apply the changes over .5s (half a second) and to change the background color over a half a second period of time. After you have read up to this point, you are probably wondering "what modifies the properties?" This brings us to the most technical part of this code...

Look carefully at the selector `a:hover:after`. The selector is a pseudo class which means that when the link is "hovered" over, to apply the CSS properties `width:100%` and `background:blue;`. As a result, the width expands to 100% of the a tag (remember the a tag acts like a parent element) and the background changes to blue over a half second period.

Here are some suggestions for you if you are going to use this on a website. You will want to use a hex code instead of `blue` in the transition and you will also want to use the `transition` property with vendor prefixes to offer better browser support.

Here is what the final result of your code should look like.

```
a:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    -moz-transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
    transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: #0000FF;
}
```

Hope this helps. Please ask any questions if you still don't understand something mentioned.

Comment: Damn. Why isn't this higher up?

Answer (score 0):

### CSS Virtual Pseudo-Elements

To start, you need to understand CSS's virtual pseudo-elements.  For every element on the page, `<div>`, `<a>`, anything, there are two others.  Hidden by default, these elements can be accessed by the css selectors `#myelement:before` and `#myelement:after`.

By setting the CSS style `content: ''` on those elemnts they will appear on the page.  Then can then be styled with any other styles just about like any other element.

---

### The `border`-less trick

In this particular example, there is no `border` used.  Instead, the `:after` element is shown and used to create a `3px` tall box with a `background-color` right under the link.  That widening effect is created by setting `width: 0;` and then animating to `width: 100%;`.

The code snippet you saw:

```
<a href="www.ign.com">Link</a>

a:after {
    ...
}
```

works pretty much the same as:

```
<a href="www.ign.com">Link<span class="after"></span></a>

a .after {
    ...
}
```

[This JSFiddle works the same way](https://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/kLdcb8o7/2/), except without the confusing (but pretty cool once you understand it) `:after` pseudo-element.

Comment: ah your JSFiddle looks so much simpler than using pseudo elements!

Comment: @jimbo123  Yep, it's easier to understand.  I really recommend learning pseudo-elements.  For example, it would be a pain to put in or change that `<span class="after"></span>` after *every* link in a long write-up when `:after` can do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

There's an explanation and demonstration here:

https://www.rgraph.net/blog/an-example-of-an-animated-expanding-underline-menu-effect.html

And the code from  is thus (this is a whole example of a page that you can copy into a file and run):

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div#menubar {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            background-color: #eee;
        }

        div#menubar span {
            display:inline-block;
            margin: 10px 2% 10px 2%;
        }

        div#menubar span::after {
          display: block;
          position: relative;
          top: 3px;
          content: '';
          border-bottom: solid 3px #019fb6;  
          transform: scaleX(0);  
          transition: transform .25s ease-in-out;
        }

        div#menubar span:hover::after {
            transform: scaleX(1);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="menubar">
        <span>Item 1</span>
        <span>Item 2</span>
        <span>Item 3</span>
        <span>Item 4</span>
        <span>Item 5</span>
        <span>Item 6</span>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```